# printing a column after a specific pattern from a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have these lines of data. I want to just print the numbers that follows A, C and D. Is there a way to print those columns?

```
 (((A 0.0400213  B 0.0400213  0.00737467  C 0.047396  0.03466  D 0.082056 ;
 ((C 0.0275027  (A 0.023266  B 0.023266  0.00423667  0.0131187  D 0.0406213 ;
 ((C 0.0310553  (B 0.0210907  A 0.0210907  0.00996467  0.0222647  D 0.05332 ;
 ((C 0.03491  (A 0.020474  B 0.020474  0.014436  0.0221067  D 0.0570167 ;
 ((C 0.0485573  (A 0.00938133  B 0.00938133  0.039176  0.00335133  D 0.0519087 ;
```

If I want to get the numbers following A
My expected out come will be :

```
0.0400213,
0.023266,
0.0210907,
0.020474,
0.00938133
```

Comment: I tried to make an awk file that contain this line /A/ {print $2} and used this code awk -f branchpick.awk temptree4.nex. temptree.nex contain above data and branchpick.awk is the awk file.

Comment: Just `A` or `(((A` and `((A` too?

Comment: I used just A not others

Comment: @DivyagashSwargaloganathan: It would be much better if you also provide your expected output by editing your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/A|C|D/) printf $++i FS; print ""}' file
```

#### Output:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/A|C|D/) printf $++i FS; print ""}' file
0.0400213 0.047396 0.082056 
0.0275027 0.023266 0.0406213 
0.0310553 0.0210907 0.05332 
0.03491 0.020474 0.0570167 
0.0485573 0.00938133 0.0519087
```

#### More verbose:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/A|C|D/) { gsub(/[(]/,"",$i) ; printf $i " is " $++i FS }; print ""}' file
A is 0.0400213 C is 0.047396 D is 0.082056 
C is 0.0275027 A is 0.023266 D is 0.0406213 
C is 0.0310553 A is 0.0210907 D is 0.05332 
C is 0.03491 A is 0.020474 D is 0.0570167 
C is 0.0485573 A is 0.00938133 D is 0.0519087
```

#### Update:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/A/){gsub(/[(]/,"",$i);print $++i}}' file
0.0400213
0.023266
0.0210907
0.020474
0.00938133
```

Comment: I think the output that you gave is not what I needed. The first column of the output is just the first column of the data. However, when I modified your code as '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/A/) printf $++i FS; print ""}' file, I got the numbers following A and when I change to '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/C/) printf $++i FS; print ""}' file, I got the numbers following C. That is what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DivyagashSwargaloganathan Updated the answer. You can work your way out from here. This should be a good starting point.

Comment: It's already in the question, but here it is again 0.0400213, 0.023266, 0.0210907, 0.020474, 0.00938133

Comment: +1 for spending 30 mins on this :P Can `if($i~/A/||$i~/C/||$i~/D/)` be shortened to `if($i~/A|C|D/)` ?

Comment: Yes, I have figured out how to get the rest of the answer, thank you for your answer !

Comment: @anubhava It sure can ... I'm humbled!

Comment: @JS웃: You're most welcome, thanks for incorporating my suggestion into your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$sed -r 's/.*(A\s)([0]\.[0-9]+).*/\2/' file
0.0400213
0.023266
0.0210907
0.020474
0.00938133
```